# Change Prestashop 1.5.6.2 customer password requirements

Tags: php, passwords, prestashop, requirements, prestashop-1.5

I'm looking for a way to make some requirements on the customer registration form on Prestashop 1.5.6.2, so that the password should be at least six characters long and contain at least one capital letter.

The first thing with at least six characters is done, but need to configure the requirement of at least one capital letter in the password. Does anyone know how to do so?

Older customers should still be able to login with their old password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the Validate::isPasswd() method. That's all.

Comment: Okay, so the below will have to be overridden, right?

 /**
  * Check for password validity
  *
  * param string $passwd Password to validate
  * param int $size
  * return boolean Validity is ok or not
  */
 public static function isPasswd($passwd, $size = 6)
 {
  return (Tools::strlen($passwd) >= $size && Tools::strlen($passwd) < 255);
 }
 public static function isPasswdAdmin($passwd)
 {
  return Validate::isPasswd($passwd, 8);
 }

Comment: Exactly. You need to create an override file, in which this method is overriden.

Comment: Well I got a different situation.

I want to validate the password field for upper case, lower case, number and special character so I have configured my 
The customer part is working good. But the Admin doesn't load.
I investigated and found that isPasswdAdmin() also calls the isPasswd () and my admin password doesn't satisfy that condition. So I renamed the isPasswd() inside  isPasswdAdmin() and added a new method with the older isPasswd() content. That didn't work. Again I
Changed my admin password to satisfy the isPasswd() but still that didn't work.
Any solution guys?

Answer (score 0):

For smarty validation
file path
/project_folder/themes/theme_name/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl

```
<input
          class="form-control js-child-focus js-visible-password"
          name="{$field.name}"
          type="password"
          value=""
          pattern="{literal}(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$%^&@#]).{8,}{/literal}"
          oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, one special symbol($%^&@#) and at least 8 or more characters.')"
          oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
          {if $field.required}required{/if}
        >
```

For back end validation, override the Validate::isPasswd() or define new method to validate pattern